# expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’ --argv

Tags: c, shell, process, argv

I am trying to create a simple shell which takes something like "ls" or "ls -l" and executes it for me.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void execute(char **argv)
{
  int status;
  int pid = fork();
  if ((pid = fork()) <0)
     {
       perror("Can't fork a child process\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
  if (pid==0)
     {
    execvp(argv[0],argv);
        perror("error");
     }
  else
     {
      while(wait(&status)!=pid) 
         ;
     }


}

int main (int argc, char **argv)

{

   char args[256];
   while (1)
   {
      printf("shell>");
      fgets(args,256,stdin);
      if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit")==0)
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      execute(args);
   }

}
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
basic_shell.c: In function ‘main’:
basic_shell.c:42: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘execute’ from incompatible pointer type
basic_shell.c:8: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
```

Can you please give me some pointers on how to correctly pass the arguments to my execute function?

Comment: whenever I see someone asking for some pointers I remeber that xkcd comic...

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you're passing a single string to `execute()`, which is expecting an array of strings.  You'll need to break up `args` into the component arguments so that `execute()` can handle them properly.  [`strtok(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

`note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char *’` says all.

What else you need ?

`args` is decaying to `char *` but you have `char **` for `void execute(char **argv)`

You need to split your `args` into

- command
- options

Use [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function